# Rails 5 - where can I find the rules for using javascript with Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to broaden the scope of my search for help so that I can use javascript with my Rails 5 app in production, hosted on heroku.

I've set out the full detail of my issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082357/rails-figuring-out-the-javascript-config). I wasn't able to find help in reply to that post, but I can see from the commentary that others provided and the suggestions made that there must be a set of rules for using javascript or jQuery in a Rails 5 app, which I cannot find published anywhere.

I have been through the rails guides, I have done every course available on code school to learn javascript and on gorails to try to learn some rails. I have 10+ text books and can't find the configuration for rails + javascript covered anywhere. I've been trying a this for 4+ years.

So - please - if you know of a resource that sets out the rules for how to use javascript with a rails 5 app, please could you give me that reference.

I know formulating questions in this way is against the rules of StackOverflow. I accept this post will likely be down voted. I'm asking because this is a last ditch desperate request for help. I cant go on for another year trying to learn something for which teaching is not available. I recall thinking in October 2012 that I could start a computer science degree to try to learn - but dismissing the idea on the basis that there are so many language driven guides that I stupidly thought I could use to learn. I cant get past step 1 because I can't solve the problem outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082357/rails-figuring-out-the-javascript-config).

Comment: Was the javascript rails-guide not helpful? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html if not - can you explain what is missing that you need?

Comment: Can you tell in the question what exactly you want using gmaps4rails gem?

Comment: @TarynEast - good point. I'll redraft this note to identify all the open ended things in the Rails Guides. I can see from Brenzy's suggestion on my linked post that he thinks its effective to remove everything and then add js files back one by one to find incompatible js. But how do I now what the compatibility rules are? Where are they defined? Once I find them, I might have half a chance of fixing something.

Comment: @uDay I'm not using the gmaps4rails gem